# How to run a console application with command line parameters in Visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: c++, command-line, parameters, visual-c++-6

I've got a console application that compiles and executes fine with Visual C++ 6.0, except that it will then only get as far as telling me about missing command line parameters. There doesn't seem to be anywhere obvious to enter these. How do I run or debug it with command line parameters?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I assume you're talking about setting the command line parameters for running in the IDE.

Open the Project/Settings property page and go to the Debug tab.

There's a "Program arguments" field you can put them into.

Answer (score 8):

If I remember correctly, under Project/Settings/Debug tab there is a place to enter the command line parameters. It's the "Program arguments" field.

Answer (score 4):

In VS2010: 
Right click the project.
Select Properties.
Select Debug tab.
Start Options -> Command line arguments: Enter the arguments here.

Comment: How to see the console app's output? It just run and quit when I debug it in VS2010 IDE.